# A second Boot Loop, any underlying causes?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, custom-roms, boot-loop

Recently, a while after I rooted my Galaxy SII, I decided to take the plunge and flash a custom rom.

I went with the stable slimbean roms, It survived for a little over a month or two, with 1 maybe 2 updates to newer builds, but about 2.5 weeks back, it went into a boot loop.

I tried most solutions I could find, and nothing helped, so in the end I flashed AOKP rom, and that worked really well for 2 weeks. Now even that is stuck in a boot loop.

I am trying to figure out if these are one off things or if it is something I am doing wrong or could it be a hardware fault?

Details-

1. When I went from slimbean - AOKP, I did do a clean wipe (tried once without wipe and it was stuck in boot loop) but after the clean wipe I came across Nandroid Manager, and used it to restore my user apps data back.
2. The couple of days before it died I experienced some general sporadic slowdown along with a wierd problem that sometimes it would completely freeze when playing a song for a second or 2. I put that down to either sdcard issues or song corruption, but now I am not sure.

Comment: Those bootloops may happen because the ROMs you are using are not stable enough. and may by you do something on your phone that the ROM that you are using does not like(keeping in mind that may by the rom you are using is not so stable). I recommand reisntalling again a custom rom, but you allways have to do a full wipe of your phone and clear dalvik cache!

Answer (score 1):

You could try connecting the phone to PC and reboot. After powering down, start  `adb logcat` on computer. In this way you could see system logs during booting and may find what's wrong with the phone.

Comment: I Tried, but didnt get anything, I assumed the phone side of the logging hadnt started yet? let me try again

Comment: yup, nothing, clean flashing a new rom now.. hope this one sticks